# Send system broadcasts to only Managed profile applications

Tags: android, android-for-work

I am having a app in both user profile as well as managed profile (AFW). I am trying to send broadcast based on package name. 
intent.setPackage(packageName);
mContext.sendBroadcastAsUser(intent, UserHandle.ALL);

Result is both apps (user and managed profiles) get the broadcast.

I want to send broadcast to only managed profile app (So basically user profile should not receive the )

Comment: I want to ask you If you are able to perform  mContext.sendBroadcastAsUser(intent, UserHandle.ALL); I read that it can be done for system apps only.(Is it true ?)

Comment: Yes I am able to perform and you are right. mContext.sendBroadcastAsUser(intent, UserHandle.ALL) can be accessed only from system apps. I am sending this broadcast from PhoneWindowManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to send broadcast only to managed profile if we can get managed profile userid.

Now to get userid, we need to listen to broadcast of Managed Profile added.

```
Intent.ACTION_MANAGED_PROFILE_ADDED
```

Steps to register to listen for this broadcast,

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MANAGED_PROFILE_ADDED);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MANAGED_PROFILE_REMOVED);
context.registerReceiver(mManagedProfileListener, filter);
```

Now inside onReceive, how to get userid,

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_MANAGED_PROFILE_ADDED.equals(intent.getAction())
        && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_USER)) {
        UserHandle handle = intent.getExtras().getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_USER);
        userid = handle.getIdentifier();
   }
}
```

Now send broadcast to that userid (only system can send this broadcast),

```
mContext.sendBroadcastAsUser(intent, new UserHandle(userid));
```

Note: userid is actually the folder name which is created under /data/user whenever a managed profile or AFW (Android For Work) is configured on device.